# Allow PRs to be merged even if the commit status fails

Tags: git, github

I want to set up a tool that updates my commit status of my PRs based on some result.

However, since I want to run this in dry-run mode, I want my PRs to be mergeable even if the status update fails.

Is this possible in GitHub?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is the default setting in GitHub, as long as you don't enable any Branch Protection Rules on your repository:

> If required status checks aren't enabled, collaborators can merge the branch at any time, regardless of whether it is up to date with the base branch. This increases the possibility of incompatible changes.

[See the Protected Branches documentation here](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/defining-the-mergeability-of-pull-requests/about-protected-branches#require-status-checks-before-merging).